# Why doesn't nhibernate LINQ support simple outer joins (given a where clause on the outer joined table)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate

i have **tableA** and **tableB**

tableA has a **B_Id** property.

This query works fine:

```
 IEnumerable<A> a = Session.Query<A>().Fetch(r=>r.B);
```

but i want something like:

```
 IEnumerable<A> a = Session.Query<A>().Where(r=>r.B.Active).Fetch(r=>r.B);
```

it seems like when i do this, it no longer does a simple outer join and if there are no active records in table B, i get no results.

I want to do a pure outerjoin that will still give me results but with the B property of the A entity as null.

Does nhibernate LINQ support this ability to put a where clause on your outerjoined table??

Comment: Could you show us the sql statements that are executed, and the ones you want to execute?

Comment: @Simon Svensson - its quite simple, the code above stick a NOT outside the join so it returns no rows if there are no B.Active records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post on the nhusers group](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/419e58a55202cdba) it's apparently not supported, and you'll have to use HQL.

As to the why, I would speculate that the authors plan to add it but had higher priorities. Personally I'd see it as a key feature.

Answer (score 0):

Guess: `.Where(a => a.B == null || a.B.Active)`

A thought: You're trying to select instances of A which will be in an unknown state. How should NHibernate differ between instances of A where B == null and B.Active == false?

Both will, if it worked, return null values for B and A would be populated with a null reference. What should happen if you save A again? Should the reference to B be set to null? That would remove references when B.Active == false. Should it be untouched? That would make NHibernate store a state which doesn't represent your domain object.

Comment: @Simon Svensson - isn't that the basics of an outer join.  Show me all records from one table regardless if the other table has valid record

Comment: Yes, but how does that apply to a domain model which needs to know if it's reference to B is meant to be null, or if it is null just because there's no B matching the filter? The underlying query doesn't tell NHibernate anything about that.

Comment: @Simon Svensson - so is there anyway to write an outerjoin in this case with a where clause that simple will return null in that reference (compared to not returning any records at all)

Comment: What sql does my guessed filter produce? I would guess a projection on top of that would work.

Comment: @Simon Svensson - what do you mean "a projection on top of that" ??

Comment: `.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.B })` would return a projection (Id and B) instead of a domain object. Projections aren't managed by NHibernate, and can't be written back to the database.